# If and only if end of string

Tags: php, regex, security

To assert the end of a string with a regex you can use `$`

From what I've read though this is exactly what it does:

**$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)**

So this means it's not quite true, for example it wouldn't make a difference if I appended `\n` to a string when using `$`.

In my case this would be a security flaw in my PHP code as I use this regex to validate alphanumeric usernames on registration:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Is there a way to strictly assert if and only if it's the end of the string with a regex?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151410/discussion-on-question-by-super-if-and-only-if-end-of-string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to make sure you match at the very end of the string with a PCRE regex.

You may use `\z` anchor that matches at the very end of the string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/
```

Or, you may use a `D` modifier:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/D
```

The  `PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY` modifier `D` makes the `$` anchor match at the *very end of the string* (excluding the position before the final newline in the string), i.e. act as `\z` anchor.

Comment: Nice and elegant.

Comment: Which one would you prefer?

Comment: I would prefer fewer modifiers (they redefine the behavior of something, and that is not straight-forward). I'd use `\z`, it is the most straight-forward way for me.